# Adding multiple items using the raw_id_field popup

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using the Django admin site and I have a m2m relation which uses raw_id_fields in the admin panel. A user can add an item to the m2m model using the popup window but I would like to be able to select multiple items at once and add them all.

Is this at possible with the current framework or would customisation be needed. If customisations are needed, how would I go about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

[django-bulk-admin](https://github.com/purelabs/django-bulk-admin) will do the trick, and it supports other bulk actions in admin.